# How can I add a new index evenly in a list?

Tags: python

I would like to add number 0 to every separator position ',' in a list.
for example, I will take a random positive user input such as [1928, 293,393].
then I would insert 0 to the index evenly for example, [1928, 0, 293, 0, 393].
Finally, I would combine all the number in the list by 0 to make a one form say, 192802930393 as output.

```
def to_str_l(l):
    str_l= [str(i) for i in l]
    return str_l



def encode(l):
    l= to_str_l(l)
    if len(l) >= 1 and len(l)< 2:
        l[1:1]= ["0"]
    elif len(l) > 2 and len(l)< 5:
        l[-1:-1]= ["0"]
    elif len(l) > 5:
        pass
    return l
s= [1928, 293, 393]
print(encode(s))
out: ['1928', '293', '0', '393']
```

here I thought int to str and slicing list but it does not really work so. I just began learning python, any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: If the goal is merely that final joined string, there's no need to actually insert zeros into the list: `"0".join(to_str_l(l))` would do that directly.

Answer (score 0):

All these steps aren't necessary to get to the final result, but here's just what you said you wanted to do:

```
s= [1928, 293, 393]

for i in range(len(s)-1, 0, -1):
    s.insert(i, 0)

print(s)

acc = ""
for i in range(0, len(s)):
    acc += str(s[i])

print(acc)
```

Result:

```
[1928, 0, 293, 0, 393]
192802930393
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
def masaaki(list_of_number):
    return '0'.join(list_of_number)
```

I'm sorry I used your name as the function name.

```
>>> result = masaaki(['123','456','789'])
>>> print(result)
>>> 12304560789
```

Comment: you need to convert the numbers to `str` first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want just with 2-3 lines of code:

```
s= [1928, 293, 393]

[s.insert(i+i+1,0) for i in range(len(s)-1)]

s = [str(elem) for elem in s]

print(''.join(s))
```

Output:

```
192802930393
```